# Propositional logic problem

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Show that [ (p ∨ q) ∧ (p → r) ∧ (q → r) ] → r is a tautology (without a truth table).

I am new to this, so I am not quite sure of how some rules can be used. Here is what I have so far:

```
= [(p ∨ q) ∧  (¬p v r)  ∧   (¬q v r) ] → r           by logical equivalence

=¬[(p ∨ q) ∧  (¬p v r)  ∧   (¬q v r) ] v r           by logical equivalence

=¬(p v q)   v ¬(¬p v r)  v  ¬(¬q v r)   v r           by DeMorgan’s law

= (¬p ^ ¬q) v  (p  ^ ¬r) v   (q ^ ¬r)   v r           by DeMorgan’s law
```

EDIT (does this work?)

```
=    r v (¬r ^ p) v  (¬r ^q) v (¬p ^ ¬q)            just switched things around 

=    r v (¬r  v (p ^ q)) v (¬p ^ ¬q)                distributive law
         ^             ^ are these parenthesis required? 
=    (r v (¬p ^ ¬q)) v (¬r  v (p ^ q))              just switched things around

=     T                                             by negation laws
```

First of all, please correct me if I have made any mistakes here and tell me if I am on the right track. Second, I am just not sure what I can do next. I wanted to try using distributive laws to break (q ^ ¬r)   v r up, and then use negation laws to finish, but I am not sure if that's legal.

Also, my book states: ¬(p ∨ q) = ¬p ^ ¬q. Since the parenthesis are no longer there, does that mean I would be able to move ¬p and ¬q around afterwards? Or was it just a 'mistake' in the print?

Comment: Your computations so far look correct. It is also the case that $(p\wedge ¬r)\vee(q\wedge ¬r)= (p\vee q)\wedge ¬r$.

Comment: Your last question about $\neg p \wedge \neg q$ is this: you can commute $\wedge$ and $\vee$ seperately, i.e. $p \wedge q \equiv q \wedge p$ but you can not commute them together, so in general, no you can just not move around the $\neg p$ and the $\neg q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ denote contradiction, and $t$ denote tautology.

$$( (p \vee q) \wedge (p \rightarrow r) \wedge ( q \rightarrow r) ) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv ((p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) ) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv (((p \vee q) \wedge \neg p) \vee ((p \vee q) \wedge r))) \wedge (\neg q \vee r)) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv (((p \wedge \neg p) \vee (q \wedge \neg p)) \vee ((p \vee q) \wedge r))) \wedge (\neg q \vee r)) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv (c \vee (q \wedge \neg p) \vee ( p \wedge r) \vee (q \wedge r)) \wedge (\neg q \vee r)) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv (((q \wedge \neg p) \wedge (\neg q \vee r)) \vee ((p \wedge r) \wedge (\neg q \vee r)) \vee ((q \wedge r) \wedge (\neg q \vee r))) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv ((q \wedge \neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (q \wedge \neg p \wedge r) \vee (p \wedge r \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge r \wedge r)) \vee ((q \wedge r) \wedge (\neg q \vee r))) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv ((q \wedge \neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (q \wedge \neg p \wedge r) \vee (p \wedge r \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge r \wedge r)) \vee ((q \wedge r \wedge \neg q) \vee (q \wedge r \wedge r))) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv c \vee (q \wedge \neg p \wedge r) \vee ((p \wedge r \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge r)) \vee ( c \vee (q \wedge r)) \rightarrow r$$
$$\equiv \neg (((q \wedge \neg p \wedge r) \vee (p \wedge r \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge r) \vee (q \wedge r)) \wedge \neg r)$$
$$\equiv \neg ( (q \wedge \neg p \wedge r \wedge \neg r) \vee (p \wedge r \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg r) \vee (p \wedge r \wedge \neg r) \vee (q \wedge r \wedge \neg r))$$
$$\equiv \neg (c \vee c \vee c \vee c)$$ $$\equiv t$$

One way to think about this is to try and make it not a tautology.  What would that look like? Well the only way an implication can be false is if the hypothesis is true, while the conclusion is false.  That would mean that $r$ is false and then $(p \vee q) \wedge (p \rightarrow r) \wedge ( q \rightarrow r)$ is true, but then for that to happen, since $r$ is false, $p, q$ have to be false (because of $p \rightarrow r$ and $q \rightarrow r$) but then $p \vee q$ is false, so the hypothesis is false.  Hence, we have a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

Assume everything in the antecedent true.  Then each of the conjuncts qualifies as true.  Suppose "p".  Then, by detachment and (p $\rightarrow$ r), we may infer "r".  Suppose "$\lnot$p".  Then by disjunctive syllogism and (p $\lor$ q), we may infer q.  Since we have (q $\rightarrow$ r) also, we may infer "r" by detachment.  By the principle of bivalence it follows that "r" holds.  By conditional introduction with our original assumption, and soundness, the above qualifies as a tautology.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already know that the statement is in fact a tautology, I need to show how it is in the form of a proof. Its a bit hard to follow what you are describing (I am not up-to-date with the spiffy key words) so it turns into jargon in my head. +1, though I can't tell if the answer to the proof is in there. Let me know what you think of the current proof I have if you could!

Comment: @Colton In order to determine if you have a proof in the formal sense or not we need to know exactly what your rules of inference say.  Your last step I find the most questionable.  In general, your other steps probably do NOT violate the rules, but they do not follow them either.  Your first use of "De Morgan's law" involves two conjunctions simultaneously.  Does your rule say that, or does it imply it?  If it implies it, you would do better to show that you can use such a rule first.  Also, you used the associative and commutative properties of $\land$ and $\lor$ simultaneously... again

Comment: what you did does NOT cause any invalidity, but you would do better if you showed that your rules allow exactly what you did first.  The last step is by no means clear at all.  Since you write in infix notation, you need to include parentheses or at least make it very clear as to how you would restore parentheses to all of your expressions.  You are not clear as to how you would do this yet, so I suggest including all parentheses.  This means that instead of writing p $\lor$ q you actually need to write (p $\lor$ q) or (p) $\lor$ (q).  Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, my book is a little wishy-washy about the parenthesis (and I did ask about them in the post :p), I couldn't find any good examples, and the notation is not explained either.